# Ubuntu 18.10 does not boot correctly until I disable touchpad

Tags: boot

I have a problem.
When I start Ubuntu it tells me CPU stuck 22s but when I disable the touchpad with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> the boot continues.
What should I do to not always press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and start the Ubuntu alone?

Answer (score 0):

Is your machine custom built?
This problem may be caused by the power supply:

> In the end I slowly became suspicious of the power supply in this computer. It is hard to quantify exactly why, but the suggestions from "pqwoerituytrueiwoq" got me looking at the voltage levels provided by the "sensors" linux command-line program, and the voltages reported by the BIOS, and somehow I decided that it was worth replacing the power supply. 
>  I bought a small (500W) new power supply made by what I feel is a reputable company and made the swap.
>   
>  GREAT NEWS: After replacing the power supply, the crashes completely stopped! I wanted to wait a while just to be sure, but it is now a few weeks since the new powersupply went in, and I haven't had a single crash since. The power supply is not something that I would normally worry about, but in this case it totally fixed my problem.

See [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2205211) for full post.

Comment: is  acer laptop .